# Signal filtering, what's wrong with the circuit?

Tags: pcb, circuit-analysis, circuit-design, electricity, protocol

I have this circuit where I receive a protocol signal:

[image]

The `+L_IN` signal is this:

[image] 
This signal has a 28V DC voltage.

The signal at `+Loop_Protocol`:

[image]
(this signal might not be the best measure, because the ground was connected to the ground oscilloscope with a wire, it might have a 50Hz its not supposed)

The `+Loop_Protocol` goes to two other circuit parts:

The protocol filtering circuit, which is supposed to strip the DC part of the protocol:

[image]

It will go to a pin port of a pic.

The signal at the protocol filter from central, at `DATA_IN` is giving a signal that doesn't seem right:

[image]

And the other circuit is the one that provides 3V3:

[image]

The signal at `DATA_IN` needs to be clean, only without the DC.

The strange thing is that if I remove the capacitor `C24` in the circuit `3.3V Regulator from Loop`, the signal turns out good. The reason I put the diode BAV70 in this circuit is because that same capacitor was destroying the signal.

Anyone know what can be done to solve this?

Note: When taking the pictures with the oscilloscope I accidentally left it with the option to measure AC only and to invert the signal.  I don't have the possibility to take new pictures now.

Note2: About the BD9G101G it has a high impedance in EN pin, about 550kohm, about Vcc I haven't seen it mentioned on the datasheet

Comment: What is your expected output? Also, I'm not understanding the way you are using the word "protocol." What do you mean by it?

Comment: hello @Justin, by protocol i mean a XP95 protocol the signal is transmiting it.

Comment: What is the purpose of the high/bandpass filter R77 R79 C21 C26? What is the purpose of filtering the digital signal?

Comment: Hi @laptop2d it's to remove the DC component of the signal, that is about 28/30V

Comment: What is the fastest rise time of the +L_IN signal? And the fastest period between rising and falling or falling and rising?

Comment: @laptop2d I'm not looking at it right now,  but from what I remember it's 250us

Comment: @justin the expected output is the signal without the DC component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my understanding of the circuit. We need to know the minimum and maximum pulse widths on the incoming serial data. I have just assumed a square wave to get started. We also need to know more about the load on IC9, I have just assumed two load states.

You need more signal conditioning, the transistor that was removed was probably useful. I added a diode ("new") to offset the signal above zero. You probably need more than this.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvi5HD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

Comment: Hello @Mattman944 tks a lot for answer. The BD9G101G after reading from datasheet I supose it has a lot more impedance than that, at least in EN it mentions it has 550kohm. The maximum of a pulse is about 1ms, the signal is inverted on the first image. This 3V3 will be used on other parts of circuit including for the Pic microcontroller.

Comment: the transistor is used to invert the signal, for inverted logic on the Pic microcontroller, but I discovered a problem with the direct signal, it has more than 4V AC, and the pin of the Pic that receives it is not supposed to receive more than 3V3, at least using the transistor and the resistor that is above it, that part is solved. Hope that it wasn't enough to damage the pin of the Pic microcontroller.

Comment: This circuit seems awesome i think i solved most of the problem with a Zener to the ground at the anode of D1 and before the Zener a resistance to not aftect the Signal IN.